# Best way to get the value of a given URL parameter with Javascript / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose you have a URL:

```
http://www.example.com/whatever?this=that&where=when
```

How would you extract the value of the `where` parameter (in this case `when`)?

This is what I came up with -- I'm wondering if there's a better solution:

```
$.fn.url_param_value = function(param) {
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  var regex = new RegExp(param + "=");

  return $.grep(url.split("?")[1].split("&"), function(a) {
    return a.match(regex);
    })[0].split("=")[1];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

use **[jquery.query](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object)** and have fun :)

you can simply use:

```
var w = $.query.get("where");
```

Comment: Query string object is an extension creates a singleton query string object for quick and readable query string modification and creation. This plugin provides a simple way of taking a page's query string and creating a modified version of this with little code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are left without jQuery, here is a function I use:

```
function urlParam(name, w){
    w = w || window;
    var rx = new RegExp('[\&|\?]'+name+'=([^\&\#]+)');
    var val = w.location.href.match(rx);
    return !val ? '':val[1];
}
```

w is an optional parameter(defaulted to window) if you need to read iframe parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I use this bit of javascript from [Netlobo.com](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html)

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

or if you are looking for a plugin, try [jQuery URL Parser](http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/)

*Edit: Hmm, nm I guess TheVillageIdiot's suggestion is the best & easiest for jQuery :P... YAY, I learned something new today :) But you should still check out the plugin, it's nice in that it will return [any part](http://stevenlevithan.com/demo/parseuri/js/) of the URL including data from a string.